# Rollback because of NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to assign values to attributes of activerecord from xml.
Xml provides somw attributes that are missing - they should by 'rescued'.
For some reason in the end (e.save) transaction is rolled back because of NoMethodError. Why?

```
ev = root.elements['VehicleList'].elements['Vehicle']
e = Vehicle.new
ev.elements.each do |x|
   begin 
     if(defined? e["#{x.name.downcase}"]) then
         e["#{x.name.downcase}"] = x.text 
     end 
   rescue 
      puts "Error\n"
   end   
end
e.save
```

Comment: Please change `rescue` to `rescue StandardError => e`, `puts e.join("\n")` (and then show us the output) so we can see precisely what is failing

Comment: It would be nice to have some context. Does the Vehicle class have the methods `[]` and `[]=` defined? That would be my first guess as to the problem.

Comment: Vehicle class is empty (just extension of activerecord).

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to Ruby. If I put rescue with er it returns 'Activerecord' has undefined join method. No idea why, sorry.
rescue Exception => err
      puts err.join("\n")
   end

Comment: Try `err.backtrace.join("\n")`

Comment: you can see what an object responds to with `obj.methods` by the way, and you can see it's class with `obj.class`

Comment: `defined? e["#{x.name.downcase}"]` as a test for whether your `Vehicle` model has a particular attribute isn't doing what you want. `e["some made up attribute"]` is `nil` and `defined? nil` is the string `"nil"` which will be considered true. Try using `e.has_attribute?(x.name.downcase)` instead.